Analysing an executable with a 24bit segmented address space
I have an executable of a legacy embedded system that I want to analyze.
The system uses an 80186 assembler. The architecture of the system is similar to 16bit DOS but instead of a 20bit address space this device uses a 24bit address space where the segment is shifted by 8 bits rather than by 4.
I tried opening the executable in ghidra but I get an error:

ghidra.program.model.address.AddressOverflowException: Address
Overflow in add ...

How can I analyze such an executable?
Perhaps there is a way to configure ghidra to preform address mapping differently?
Is there another reverse engineering tool that will allow me to configure address space segmentation differently?
Maybe there is some pre-processing that I can do to make this executable load in one of the already available architectures?

Are you sure that Ghidra support the extended memory mode (24bits address-space) ? The error message seems to complains about an overflow on the address-space value, so it might be the problem. So, the segmentation process might be in the line. You may have a more accurate answer by submitting an issue report directly on Ghidra's Github page.
